# Python tkinter: configure multiple labels with a loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tkinter

I have a window with multiple labels. Instead of configuring each label individually, I want to use a for loop to configure them.

Basically, what I get from the below code is all labels are showing the text 'question #3', but I want each label label to show the right text accordingly - so label1 needs to have the text 'question #1', label2 needs to show 'question #2' and label3 needs to show 'question #3'. Can somebody please help.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

string = 'Question #'

nums = ['1', '2', '3']

#labels
label_1 = Label(root)
label_1.pack()

label_2 = Label(root)
label_2.pack()

label_3 = Label(root)
label_3.pack()
# end of labels

labels = [label_1, label_2, label_3]

for x in nums:
    jk = string + x

    for l in labels:
        l.config(text=jk)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do so by only modifying your code will involve using zip. Your code just have some looping issues.

```
for x, l in zip(nums,labels): #change your for loops to this
    jk = string + x
    l.config(text=jk)
```

Writing a concise code involving this: generating the label and the text together could save you many lines of codes. This works the same for your code

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
string = 'Question #'
nums = ['1', '2', '3']
labels=[] #creates an empty list for your labels
for x in nums: #iterates over your nums
    jk = string + x
    label = Label(root,text=jk) #set your text
    label.pack()
    labels.append(label) #appends the label to the list for further use

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

result of code is given below;

[image]

code explain: I have one recipe that has a 3 foods and one drink for the small buffet.
I want pide (food)+ayran (drink), some body want kebap(food) + ayran etc.

Is it possible the customer to see three different foods plus a drink in a row?, yes of course!.
Then I coded something like below. I finally came to solution after tried many times.

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self,master,pide=14,ayran=2,kebap=16,sucuk=12): #Class variables
        self.master=master
        master.title("A simple recipe")
        self.ayran=ayran
        self.pide=pide
        self.kebap=kebap
        self.sucuk=sucuk
    

    def hesapla(self):  

        pa=self.pide+self.ayran   #food +drink
        ka=self.kebap+self.ayran
        sa=self.sucuk+self.ayran
        #print (pa)
        fiyatlar= [pa,ka,sa]  #arrays of foods+drinks
    
        for x in range(3):

            L = tk.Label( text=fiyatlar[x])    #labels for price tags in a 3 rows
            L.grid(row=x,column=1)

        yazilar=["pide+ayran=","kebap+ayran=","sucuk+ayran="]  #names of foods and drinks
        for x in range(3):

            L2 = tk.Label( text=yazilar[x])
            L2.grid(row=x,column=0)
        
        for x in range(3):

            L3 = tk.Label( text="$")   # $ sign near the price tags
            L3.grid(row=x,column=2)

    def main(): # let codes work
         uyg = Tk()
         hes1 = Class1(uyg)
         hes1.hesapla()
         uyg.mainloop()

     if __name__ == '__main__': #if you want use another .py file, call it.
     main()
```

Comment: Hi Alphard. Thanks for your answer. Usually answers with an explanation are more welcomed here. Would you like to update your answer to provide short explanation?

Comment: Yes of course. When I paste my code I have hurry. I add explain near my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

class Class1:

  def __init__(self,cam):

    self.cam = cam
    cam.title("Abcd egfh")

    self.frame1=Frame(cam, padx=5)
    self.frame1.grid(column=0,row=1)

    self.labels= ["LABELS","label 1","label 2","label 3","label 4"]
    Editlabel=Label(self.frame1,text="EDITS")
    Editlabel.grid(row=0,column=1)
    self.edits= ["ed1","ed2","ed3","ed4"]

    for x in range(5):

        self.L = Label( self.frame1,text=self.labels[x])   
        self.L.grid(row=x,column=0)

class Class2(Class1):

  def __init__(self,ws):

    super().__init__(ws)

    for x in range(1,5):

        self.L = Entry(self.frame1)   
        self.L.grid(row=x,column=1)


 root.geometry("200x150")



 my_gui = Class1(root)

 my_gui2 = Class2(root)

 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.